# Spring Boot, обновление кол-ва просмотров у публикации

Tags: java, spring, многопоточность, spring-data, spring-jpa

Нужна помощь. Пишу небольшой сайт блог с публикациями. Есть метод, который вызывается при нажатии на кнопку и содержит следующий функционал: Происходит получение с базы данных поста по ID и увеличение поля отвечающего за кол-во просмотров этого поста, код ниже:

```
public Post getPostById(long id) {
    Post post = postRepository.findById(id).get();
    post.setViews(post.getViews() + 1);
    postRepository.save(post);
    return post;
 }`
```

Вопрос в следующем: При одновременном нажатии на клавишу нескольких разных пользователей, не будет ли проблем с параллелизмом? Если будет, как корректнее реализовать мою задумку? Использовать AtomicInt?

P.S. Заранее спасибо

Comment: `AtomicInt` не поможет. Лучше делать обновление в базе `update post set views=views+1`. На уровне Ява-кода ты можешь сделать  `synchronized (update_lock)` - для приложения с одним инстансом и низкой нугрузкой будет нормально.

Comment: Хотя можно читать и модифицировать в транзакции https://stackoverflow.com/a/61472758/998126

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov , а если сделать поле «просмотры» в классе Post volatile? Или сделать метод setViews synchronised? Впервые столкнулся с такой задачей, в любом случае спасибо

Comment: Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1193348/spring-boot-db-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/1195115#1195115 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283527/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94/1283535#1283535

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA спасибо, в принципе понял куда копать и что подробнее почитать! Но уже личный «джуновский» интерес. Если метод в сервисе, который отвечает за получение объекта и увеличение у него поля - сделать synchronised / или же поле (которое обновляется) сделать volatile, добьемся мы ли параллельного эффекта?

Comment: `synchronized` метод у сервиса поможет, если сервис синглтон. Поле делать `volatile`, `AtomicXxx` и прочее - не поможет. У тебя при каждом чтении будет создаваться новый объект и при параллельном чтении будет два объекта, которые не знают друг про друга. Сделай транзакцию.